# Unable to migrate MediaWiki from MySQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, migration, mediawiki

good people of Stack Overflow.

I've been trying to migrate a very old installation of MediaWiki from MySQL to PostrgreSQL database, but I got to multiple dead ends. The currently running version is 1.26.1. Unfortunately, database integrity cannot be guaranteed, because the wiki was set up back in 2012 and all the db tables are running on MyISAM engine.

The **main goal** is to put everything in docker with PostgreSQL while saving all of the MediaWiki contents, authors and page history.

I've created a local copy of the database and MediaWiki on my local machine and successfully upgraded to version 1.34 (with the update.php script). Then I tried:

**1. Load db using pgloader**

The pgloader successfully migrated the MySQL db into PostgreSQL. Configured `$wgDBmwschema`. The `update.php` crashes.

```
./update.php 
MediaWiki 1.34.1 Updater

Your composer.lock file is up to date with current dependencies!
Going to run database updates for cz_improliga_wiki-cz_improliga_wiki-
Depending on the size of your database this may take a while!
Abort with control-c in the next five seconds (skip this countdown with --quick) ... 3 0
Renaming table user to mwuser
Renaming table text to pagecontent
...skipping: index user_pkey doesn't exist.
...skipping: index user_user_name_key doesn't exist.
...skipping: index text_pkey doesn't exist.
...sequence ipblocks_ipb_id_seq already exists.
...sequence revision_rev_id_seq already exists.
...sequence text_old_id_seq already exists.
...sequence recentchanges_rc_id_seq already exists.
...sequence logging_log_id_seq already exists.
...sequence page_restrictions_pr_id_seq already exists.
...sequence uploadstash_us_id_seq already exists.
...sequence category_cat_id_seq already exists.
...category table already exists.
...page table already exists.
...querycachetwo table already exists.
...page_props table already exists.
...page_restrictions table already exists.
Creating profiling table ...done.
...protected_titles table already exists.
...redirect table already exists.
...updatelog table already exists.
...change_tag table already exists.
...user_properties table already exists.
...log_search table already exists.
...l10n_cache table already exists.
...iwlinks table already exists.
...module_deps table already exists.
...uploadstash table already exists.
...user_former_groups table already exists.
...sites table already exists.
...bot_passwords table already exists.
...obsolete table 'archive2' does not exist
...column 'updatelog.ul_value' already exists
...column 'archive.ar_deleted' already exists
...column 'archive.ar_len' already exists
...column 'archive.ar_page_id' already exists
...column 'archive.ar_parent_id' already exists
...column 'archive.ar_content_model' already exists
...column 'archive.ar_content_format' already exists
...column 'categorylinks.cl_sortkey_prefix' already exists
...column 'categorylinks.cl_collation' already exists
...column 'categorylinks.cl_type' already exists
...column 'image.img_sha1' already exists
...column 'ipblocks.ipb_allow_usertalk' already exists
...column 'ipblocks.ipb_anon_only' already exists
...column 'ipblocks.ipb_block_email' already exists
...column 'ipblocks.ipb_create_account' already exists
...column 'ipblocks.ipb_deleted' already exists
...column 'ipblocks.ipb_enable_autoblock' already exists
...column 'ipblocks.ipb_parent_block_id' already exists
...column 'filearchive.fa_deleted' already exists
...column 'filearchive.fa_sha1' already exists
...column 'logging.log_deleted' already exists
...column 'logging.log_id' already exists
...column 'logging.log_params' already exists
...column 'mwuser.user_editcount' already exists
...column 'mwuser.user_newpass_time' already exists
...column 'oldimage.oi_deleted' already exists
...column 'oldimage.oi_major_mime' already exists
...column 'oldimage.oi_media_type' already exists
...column 'oldimage.oi_metadata' already exists
...column 'oldimage.oi_minor_mime' already exists
...column 'oldimage.oi_sha1' already exists
...column 'page.page_content_model' already exists
...column 'page_restrictions.pr_id' already exists
Adding column 'profiling.pf_memory'
Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBQueryError from line 1603 of /var/www/html/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php: A database query error has occurred. Did you forget to run your application's database schema updater after upgrading? 
Query: ALTER TABLE profiling ADD pf_memory NUMERIC(18,10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
Function: Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBConnRef::query
Error: 42701 ERROR:  column "pf_memory" of relation "profiling" already exists


#0 /var/www/html/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1574): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->getQueryExceptionAndLog('ERROR:  column ...', '42701', 'ALTER TABLE pro...', 'Wikimedia\\Rdbms...')
#1 /var/www/html/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1152): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->reportQueryError('ERROR:  column ...', '42701', 'ALTER TABLE pro...', 'Wikimedia\\Rdbms...', false)
#2 /var/www/html/includes/libs/rdbms/database/DBConnRef.php(68): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->query('ALTER TABLE pro...', 'Wikimedia\\Rdbms...', 0)
#3 /var/www/html/includes/libs/rdbms/database/DBConnRef.php(292): Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBConnRef->__call('query', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/includes/installer/PostgresUpdater.php(931): Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBConnRef->query('ALTER TABLE pro...')
#5 /var/www/html/includes/installer/DatabaseUpdater.php(490): PostgresUpdater->addPgField('profiling', 'pf_memory', 'NUMERIC(18,10) ...')
#6 /var/www/html/includes/installer/DatabaseUpdater.php(454): DatabaseUpdater->runUpdates(Array, false)
#7 /var/www/html/maintenance/update.php(205): DatabaseUpdater->doUpdates(Array)
#8 /var/www/html/maintenance/doMaintenance.php(99): UpdateMediaWiki->execute()
#9 /var/www/html/maintenance/update.php(277): require_once('/var/www/html/m...')
#10 {main}
```

On the other hand, the wiki loads. Unfortunately, the encoding is incorrect making the whole Wiki unreadable and breaking links.

This is an example of the first sentence on the main page:

> ImproWiki je projekt \304\214esk\303\251 improviza\304\215n\303\255 ligy, kter\303\275 si d\303\241v\303\241 za c\303\255l sjednotit fungov\303\241n\303\255 improviza\304\215n\303\255ch kategori\303\255, dopl\305\210ovat know-how mezi improviz\303\241tory a roz\305\241\303\255\305\231it pov\304\233dom\303\255 o impru obecn\304\233.

**2. Migrate db using mediawiki_mysql2postgres.pl**

I ran the script with `--verbose --verbose`, but it gets stuck with

> Too many loops!

This is the full log output.

```
Locating the mysqldump executable
Checking that mysqldump can handle our flags
Writing file "mediawiki_upgrade.pg"
Trying to determine database version...
Old schema is from MediaWiki version 105
Writing file "mediawiki_upgrade.pg"
Reading in the Postgres schema information
  Found table mwuser
    Got a timestamp for column user_newpass_time
    Got a timestamp for column user_email_token_expires
    Got a timestamp for column user_email_authenticated
    Got a timestamp for column user_touched
    Got a timestamp for column user_registration
    Got a timestamp for column user_password_expires
  Found table actor
  Found table user_groups
    Got a timestamp for column ug_expiry
  Found table user_former_groups
  Found table user_newtalk
    Got a timestamp for column user_last_timestamp
  Found table bot_passwords
  Found table page
    Got a timestamp for column page_touched
    Got a timestamp for column page_links_updated
  Found table revision
    Got a timestamp for column rev_timestamp
  Found table revision_comment_temp
  Found table revision_actor_temp
    Got a timestamp for column revactor_timestamp
  Found table ip_changes
    Got a timestamp for column ipc_rev_timestamp
  Found table pagecontent
  Found table comment
  Found table page_restrictions
    Got a timestamp for column pr_expiry
  Found table page_props
  Found table archive
    Got a timestamp for column ar_timestamp
  Found table slots
  Found table content
  Found table slot_roles
  Found table content_models
  Found table redirect
  Found table pagelinks
  Found table templatelinks
  Found table imagelinks
  Found table categorylinks
    Got a timestamp for column cl_timestamp
  Found table change_tag_def
  Found table externallinks
  Found table langlinks
  Found table site_stats
  Found table ipblocks
    Got a timestamp for column ipb_timestamp
    Got a timestamp for column ipb_expiry
  Found table ipblocks_restrictions
  Found table image
    Got a timestamp for column img_timestamp
  Found table oldimage
    Got a timestamp for column oi_timestamp
  Found table filearchive
    Got a timestamp for column fa_deleted_timestamp
    Got a timestamp for column fa_timestamp
  Found table uploadstash
    Got a timestamp for column us_timestamp
  Found table recentchanges
    Got a timestamp for column rc_timestamp
  Found table watchlist
    Got a timestamp for column wl_notificationtimestamp
  Found table interwiki
  Found table querycache
  Found table querycache_info
    Got a timestamp for column qci_timestamp
  Found table querycachetwo
  Found table objectcache
    Got a timestamp for column exptime
  Found table logging
    Got a timestamp for column log_timestamp
  Found table log_search
  Found table job
    Got a timestamp for column job_timestamp
    Got a timestamp for column job_token_timestamp
  Found table profiling
  Found table protected_titles
    Got a timestamp for column pt_timestamp
    Got a timestamp for column pt_expiry
  Found table updatelog
  Found table category
  Found table change_tag
  Found table user_properties
  Found table l10n_cache
  Found table iwlinks
  Found table module_deps
  Found table sites
  Found table site_identifiers
Reading in schema exception information
Figuring out order of tables to dump
Too many loops!
```

I tried to get more info from the [script itself](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/source/mediawiki/browse/master/maintenance/postgres/mediawiki_mysql2postgres.pl), but I'm not a Perl person.

I also tried to figure out what are the foreign key loops in the db, but since all tables run on MyISAM, there are no Foreign Keys at all.

Any suggestions on how to proceed to achieve the main goal?

Comment: pgsql support in MediaWiki is not in great shape (there is an ongoing effort to improve it for 1.35 or maybe 1.36). Your best bet might be to dump the content to XML, import it back into a fresh install, and deal with migrating non-public data manually.

Comment: I just achieved a migration in the opposite direction (PostgreSQL → MySQL, on the grounds that Mediawiki on PostgreSQL is pretty broken) by this approach: migrate the content via an XML dump, and then reconcile user accounts and revisions with a handwritten python script.  Worked out all right in the end, but boy was it a p.i.t.a.